# How to save DataFrame as csv in streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

Hi I try to save my DataFrame as csv file in streamlit.
My program return two Dataframes to streamlit as `data`.
I want to make button that will allow to save this dataframes.
I try this simple code:

```
if st.button("Pobierz plik"):
    data[0].to_csv('file.csv',index=False)
```

But nothing hapend when i clicked on the button.
Any one have some idea?

Comment: Do you want to save the file locally or do you want it to be downloaded from Streamlit?

Comment: @Pluviophile I want to download if from Streamlit

Comment: Which streamlit version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `st.download_button`

For **streamlit > 1.0.0**

> Display a download button widget.
>
> This is useful when you would like to provide a way for your users to download a file directly from your app.
>
> Note that the data to be downloaded is stored in-memory while the user is connected, so it's a good idea to keep file sizes under a couple hundred megabytes to conserve memory.

A working example can be found [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button)

In your case

```
@st.cache
 def convert_df(df):
     # IMPORTANT: Cache the conversion to prevent computation on every rerun
     return df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')

csv = convert_df(data[0])

st.download_button(
     label="Download data as CSV",
     data=csv,
     file_name='large_df.csv',
     mime='text/csv',
 )
```

Comment: Working wonders, added some args to the df.to_csv command to personalize it even more. Thank you very much !